# I cant get my form to work on heroku using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I've spent the last 4 hours just trying different things to figure out why the emails and errors i get on heroku are happening. Im very new to Rails this is my second app, so please dumb it down and talk to me like a small child, lol

http://dev-match-matt-napper.herokuapp.com/contacts/new
This is my heroku link and when you click submit it says something went wrong. I am following the simpleCodeCast on udemy videos, no response from him yet.

https://github.com/Mnapper3/simpleCodeCasts_saas
this is my git hub the files (master) i used were:

```
app/controller/contacts_controller
app/mailers/contact_mailer
app/models/contact
app/contact_mailer/contact_email.html
app/views/contacts/new.html
```

really hope i have given you enough info to help me, or maybe you could put in how you create form emailers? or link a video

P.S. im using cloud9 & if you clone this app you need to :

```
bundle install
bundle update
rake db:migrate
```

then you'll be able to preview it.

Please help!!! 

-Matt Napper

Comment: Please post `heroku logs`

Comment: Did you test in local I think you should check it first on local Its something parameter losing or method undefined kind of problem

Comment: the video said it would be less code to test it in heroku. It doesn't show any error in local preview in c9 but doesn't send emails either

Comment: Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25) can you post your production and development mailer settings please?

Comment: @matt napper, you haven't mailer configuration for development or production,  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add mailer configuration in /config/environments/production.rb as heroku by default runs on production mode.

Add this in your /config/environments/production.rb

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: Rails.application.secrets.domain_name,
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username,
  password: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password
}

# ActionMailer Config
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => Rails.application.secrets.domain_name }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
```

Then in /config/secrets.yml add the following in production block like,

```
production:
  domain_name: <%= ENV["DOMAIN_NAME"] %>
  email_provider_username: <%= ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"] %>
  email_provider_password: <%= ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"] %>
```

Finally, you must add these 3 environment variables on your heroku app. To add them, go to your heroku app settings page, I'm assuming it should be https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/dev-match-matt-napper/settings

There you'll see a Reveal Config Vars button, click on that and add Key as your environment variable and value as it's value. For example:

Key is: GMAIL_USERNAME

Value is: Your gmail email address

Comment: Actually you can directly put values for user_name and password in production.rb but that file will commit on git and anyone could see it if your repository is public. So to avoid that we use environment variables that are made on local machine (not in the app), and for that Heroku gives you a nice UI to add them from your app dashboard, that is how Heroku works. And secrets.yml is just a file to organize your environment variables nicely. Just keep in mind, never add sensitive information in your app or any file that will commit on git or something, use environment variables.